# Javascript: Undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am currently working on a web app that is using JavaScript as it's front end, and I'm having trouble with object keys.

I'm trying to access an object and I want to dynamically get the object key, but every time I got an error "undefined keys".

Here is my code:

```
var data = JSON.parse(response);
sites = [];

for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(data[0]).length; i++) {
    sites.push(Object.keys(data[0])[i]);
};

for (var x = 0; x < sites.length; x++) {
    for (var u = 0; u < Object.keys(data[0])[sites[x]].length; u++) {
        console.log(data[0].sites[x])
    }
}
```

With `data[0]`:

```
Array[4]
BAK
:
Array[4]
BAN
:
Array[4]
BAR
:
Array[4]
BAY
:
Array[4]
BLC
:
Array[4]
BOL
:
Array[6]
BTO
:
Array[6]
CAR
:
Array[5]
CUD
:
Array[4]
DAD
:
Array[4]
```

`sites[]` contains the keys (example: BAK, BAN, BAY, etc.).
I logged the sites and it contains the correct keys but every time I call `data[0].sites[x]` it says "unidentified keys of an object". If I set it manually `data[0].BAK[x]`, it is a success.

Hope you can help me solve and explain why this happens.

Comment: `sites` is a variable on its own, and is not a property of `data`. Have you tried using `console.log(data[0].sites[x]) `?

Comment: you can replace some specific line Object.keys(data[0]).length; replace by response.length

Comment: please add your data in literal notation.

Answer (score 0):

Try foreach loop

```js
var data = {"key1":"value1", "key_2":"value2"};

    for (let i in data){
        console.log("key: " + i);
        console.log("value: " + data[i]);
    }
```